# Objective C FTP Streams

Tags: objective-c, ftp, stream

I have a nice question here. I'm using Objective C for Mac OS X to create a class which uploads to and downloads from an FTP server. My question is:

Is it possible to read from a file on a FTP server via one stream, while writing to the same file from another stream, not letting the one stream read any further than the other has written?

I already have something in place to prevent the one stream from reading more than it should. All I need to know is can I read from a file on a FTP server while it is being written to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specific to the FTP server and the way it opens files, but in general the answer would be no. Most servers would open the file in exclusive mode when the file is downloaded.

Comment: Yup, thats 100% correct. On my test server, I saw that a "file part" was created to temporarily store the uploaded data. Only after the transfer was successfully completed, will that file be renamed to whatever it was supposed to be.